# Cannot transfer files from Google Cloud Bucket to VM instance

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to move my files from a google cloud bucket to a vm instance.  Let me first make sure that this is the right strategy for what I'm trying to accomplish.  I have 400 gigs of data and it takes an incredible amout of time just to open the files.  I need to do some parallel processing.  My laptop, I think, only allows up to four parallel processing units at a time.

First, I don't think it's possible, but just in case it is, I would like to read the files on my cloud bucket without transferring them to a VM instance.  I only believe that this is possible if the analogy of laptop to external harddrive is similar to VM instance to cloud bucket.  If this is not possible then I have to download the files from a cloud bucket.

I tried using the following code:

```
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
    print('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(
        source_blob_name,
        destination_file_name))

download_blob('as_lists1', '42.pkl', "kylefoley@instance-1:/home/kylefoley/42.pkl")
```

No error message was thrown.  But when I tried to list the contents on the instance-1 harddrive, `42.pkl` did not come up, as follows:

```
kylefoley@instance-1:~$ ls
distraction.txt  env  hey  you2.txt  you.txt
kylefoley@instance-1:~$ pwd
/home/kylefoley
```

Also, does anyone know whose bandwidth is used when I do that transfer?  If its the bandwidth I pay for then there is no point in splitting the transfer to several computers.  If is someone else's bandwidth then it would be a good idea to split the data into parts and transfer each data set to a different computer at the same time.

Comment: Hi. To answer all your questions I need to know few things. Which is the format of the files that you want to read directly from the bucket? Second, when you ask about the bandwidth are you asking for the connection between the bucket and your laptop or from the bucket to the VM Instance?

Comment: The format is in a python `pkl`.  If that format is too restrictive than I can convert it to `txt` though it would take a while.  The bandwidth I suppose would be from the bucket to the VM instance, but I guess that answers the question.  Since the data is so big I think I might send it to 100 different VM instances, if it does not cost that much.  That way I'm hoping I can send each section at the same time and speed things up by a factor of 100.

Comment: Also it seems maybe `datastore` is better for what I want to do.  It seems like you can access data on `datastore` without downloading it. Is that right?

Comment: Datastore is a NoSQL Database. Yes you can store simple objects and files inside but I don't know if it's what you need.

Comment: Well, the objects are simple in that they are lists of 3 dimensional lists composed of  one integer and two strings. Do you have any insight into why the files aren't transfering.

Comment: Try using this command in your vm machine: `gsutil cp -r gs://Your_Bucket/* ./` ensure to give the proper permissions to your service account to access files from your bucket or to make your bucket public.

Comment: I really need to be able to do this Python.  I have 90,000 files and I need to make all sorts of exceptions is to where the files go.  I can't press enter into the terminal 90,000 times.

Comment: Also, what type of permissions do I have to give to my bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to copy the content from your bucket to a GCP VM instance is using the command   `gsutil cp -r gs://Your_Bucket/* ./` Please ensure to give the proper [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions) to your service account to access files from your bucket or to make your bucket public.

You can give Storage Object Admin, Creator or Viewer depending on the needs of your project.

You can also use python to download your files. Here is a example file that it's working for me:

```
from google.cloud import storage
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bucket_name = 'your_bucket'
    source_blob_name = 'your_object'
    destination_file_name = 'local_file'
    #DOWNLOAD
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
    print('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(source_blob_name, destination_file_name))
```

Also regarding to your other question there is a theoretical maximum bandwidth speed of 2 Gbits/second (Gbps) cap for peak performance. You can speed up the process by using ssd attached to your instance.

Comment: If you look at the code in my OP you'll see that it's exactly the same as the code you posted here.  What is ssd?  How do you get that high bandwidth speed or is it something I don't have control over? Also, from time to time I would also like to transfer files from my laptop to the VM instance with Python rather than command line. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: In your code I don't see you importing the google.cloud library so I don't know if you are doing it or no. An ssd drive is a type of hard drive you can see more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive)You don't have control over the bandwidth of a GCP Instance, you can read more about the speed connection of your Instance [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/5-steps-to-better-gcp-network-performance?hl=ml).

Comment: It's possible to have a higher connection speed (up to 100 Gbps) even directly from your personal laptop using [Google Cloud Hybrid Connectivity](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/how-to/choose-type). To transfer files from your laptop to your instance you can [use a FTP](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/google-cloud-sftp-setup-using-filezilla-client/) protocol to manage your files.

Comment: Yea, I've got the correct import statement. I'm still waiting for a solution to this problem.

Comment: Also what about reading the files on the datastorage without downloading them? Is that possible?

Comment: Ok, I found out what the problem is.  Google created a directory on my laptop with the exact same name as the VM instance hard drive that I was trying to send it to. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Actually, I guess I have to run the python program from inside the VM instance.  I'll try that though I would rather not do that.

Comment: Run your python script from your instance instead of your laptop to avoid this. Also since datastore it's a database you actually read data without downloading it.

Comment: Well, that's what I want to do is read the data without downloading it, so that seems like it would be a better fit for what I'm trying to do.  Is that right?

Comment: I wasn't aware that you was running the script from your laptop. In the last line of your script you don't need to specify the instance name. Just the route were you want your files

Comment: Yes, especially if you can insert your data as plain text this would make things a lot easier.